# Split data into lists and operate within each list using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

below are my data:

```
structure(list(region = c("global", "global", "global", "africa", 
"africa", "africa", "asia", "asia", "asia"), disease = c("hear", 
"lung", "ear", "hear", "lung", "ear", "hear", "lung", "ear"), 
    number = c(20L, 22L, 40L, 14L, 12L, 16L, 15L, 18L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I wish to obtain the rank of the number of lung disease within each region. My desired result should be a vector c(2, 3, 1) since the number of lung disease ranks the second in global among the three diseases in global, third among the three diseases in africa, and first among the three diseases in asia.

I used `group_split` to create separate lists, but I failed to do further calculation within each list. I tried `map` function but it did not work. I would therefore like to ask what should I do to obtain the desired result if I wish to operate within the tidyverse ecosystem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return complete data like your previous data, there are two options.

**option-1** using `purrr::map_dfr`

```
map_dfr((df %>% group_split(region)), ~ (as.data.frame(.) %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank(number))))

  region disease number rank
1 africa    hear     14    2
2 africa    lung     12    1
3 africa     ear     16    3
4   asia    hear     15    2
5   asia    lung     18    3
6   asia     ear     10    1
7 global    hear     20    1
8 global    lung     22    2
9 global     ear     40    3
```

**Option-2**  Using `dplyr` only

```
df %>% group_by(region) %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank(number))
# A tibble: 9 x 4
# Groups:   region [3]
  region disease number  rank
  <chr>  <chr>    <int> <int>
1 global hear        20     1
2 global lung        22     2
3 global ear         40     3
4 africa hear        14     2
5 africa lung        12     1
6 africa ear         16     3
7 asia   hear        15     2
8 asia   lung        18     3
9 asia   ear         10     1
```

Now you can filter-out a output vector easily.

```
(df %>% group_by(region) %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank(number)))[which(df$disease == "lung"), "rank"]
# A tibble: 3 x 1
   rank
  <int>
1     2
2     1
3     3
```

If you want to use `map` with `group_split`, do it like this

```
map_dfr((df %>% group_split(region)), ~ (as.data.frame(.) %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank(number)) %>% filter(disease == "lung") %>%
                                       select(region, rank)))

  region rank
1 africa    1
2   asia    3
3 global    2
```

Comment: Why not just do: `df %>% group_by(region) %>% mutate(rank = dense_rank(number)) %>% filter(disease == 'lung') %>% select(rank)`?

Comment: @JustinCocco second option in my answer is exactly this.  But I thought OP wants it through `map` family of functions that's why posted a detailed solution.

Comment: No I mean you use `[which(df[,’disease’]==“lung”, ‘rank’]` as opposed to `filter() %>% select()` and I’m just curious if there’s a reason why.